# MySql Error: Parameter '@' must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this C# method which deletes a case from the CurrentCases table. However, I am getting an error which states

> "Parameter '@userId' must be defined."

Now the USERID has a value and @userId can be found in the Sql statement as well as in the Commands parameters.

```
private static bool DeleteCaseByCaseId(string caseId, CaseRecord cr)
    {
        string sql = "DELETE FROM CurrentCases WHERE UserId=@userId AND CaseId=@caseId";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", USERID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseId", cr.Title + "¬" + USERID + "¬" + cr.CaseId);

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rows.ToString()))
        {
            cmd?.Dispose();
            LastError = "Database.CloseCase [ERROR 5] Failed to DELETE CaseId " + caseId + " From CurrentCases Table";
            return false;
        }
        else if (rows == 0)
        {
            cmd?.Dispose();
            LastError = "Database.CloseCase [ERROR 6] Failed to DELETE CaseId " + caseId + " From CurrentCases Table";
            return false;
        }

        cmd?.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
```

Can ANYONE help me with this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You create a cmd and add parameters, then you RE-CREATE the cmd and execute non-query without adding the parameters. Can this be the problem*

Comment: Just remove the second cmd = `new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Make that the answer and you get the points... Lord knows how I made that mistake.

Comment: It's ok Dave, no problem. Be well, stay safe.

Comment: I suggest you use `using` blocks for all the disposables. Doing that well will help you see when things like that are assigned, because it's being assigned where it's not being declared in a `using` block. That, and you don't have to do `cmd?.Dispose()` in so many places.